Trying to identify manufacturer logo .. circle with circle inside
Picture:

This logo is on some RF filters and I am trying to find the manufacturer.  Hopefully someone can help.

It is a SAW filter from RF360 Europe (Qualcomm + TDK)
Part number example:
B39162B4310P810


If I remember correctly it goes Epcos -> TDK -> Qualcomm. This ring was always on them though (I use these parts myself). Not so sure if it's a logo or just marking pin 1.
